# TFS 2013: Share a workspace across two computers?

Tags: tfs

Running into a problem, my boss has two computers, one at office A and one at office B. Currently, he has both TFS work spaces binded to a single, shared network folder that only he can access. He told me today that he is having trouble checking files out from office A, and checking them in at office B.

I didn't set this setup for him, but apparently this used to work just fine back when we were using SourceSafe. Is there anyway I can make this setup work for him? The collection he is using is a "server" workspace collection, if that helps. It's set to only let 1 user checkout a file at a time. If you need more information about the configuration, let me know. Although I'm no TFS wizard.

My initial research shows that his setup is not the "right" way, but since it's one person I'd like to just get it working for him if possible, or if there is a proper solution that wouldn't be radically different.

Answer (score 1):

The workspace is defined by the computer name and the workspace name so you cannot have the "same" workspace on two different computers.
You should check-in everything in office A then remap the office A workspace to a different (network shared) folder

Answer (score 1):

To share the workspace across two computer,you could use the **updateComputerName** option to tell the server that workspace is now on a different computer.To update the computer name for workspace, you'll need to run the following command.

tf workspaces WorkspaceName /login:username  /updateComputerName:OldComputerName /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection

When you execute that command, tf.exe removes the cached workspace entries that use the old computer name, calls the server to tell it the current computer name, and gets the current list of workspaces owned by you on the current computer.

More detail info you can reference Buck's blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/03/03/update-workspace.aspx